# Quickbooks prompts for user email and pass when Outlook is already open

Tags: windows-server-2016, quickbooks

Is this the intended design? Quickbooks support wasn't helpful with this issue.

If I send email from quickbooks, and quickbooks launches outlook, it's fine.

If I open outlook, I'm not prompted for email or password either.

The moment I ask to send email on Quickbooks while Outlook is already open, it asks for email and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how QuickBooks works. We use QuickBooks to send Bills and I use it myself to send invoices occasionally. So what you see is normal. QB cannot be certain the the user of QB is also the Outlook owner